# How to parse a JSON document and extract an array?

Tags: json, typescript

The code below produces an output as shown below which is wrong as per my expectation.

[image: Wrong format]

The format I expect to have is shown below. How can I achieve this? What am I doing wrong?

I try and drill-down the structure to get a list of records from `dealerListItemDToes` array however I can't figure out a way to have it in the structure below.

[image: CorrectFormat]

```
let responseData = {
  "_embedded": {
    "dealerListItemDToes": [
      {
        "id": "ab4b23bb-b58d-4012-93ea-702e37ea555a",
        "gssnID": "GSM00000001",
        "companyID": "GCM00000001",
        "mbID": "41010f",
        "name": "GINO RAG. FELICE & FIGLIO - S.p.A.",
        "website": "http://www.gino.mercedes-benz.it",
        "phone": "+39 0171 410777",
        "country": "Italy",
        "city": "Madonna",
        "postalCode": "12100",
        "address": "Madonna dellolmo",
        "description": "description",
        "createdBy": "DataAdmin",
        "updatedBy": "DataAdmin",
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "business": "PVU",
        "passengerCar": true,
        "van": true,
        "bus": false,
        "unimog": true,
        "truck": false
      },
      {
        "id": "b644a324-6858-4ac9-a2ce-a4539cee43a5",
        "gssnID": "GSM00000002",
        "companyID": "GCM00000002",
        "mbID": "42010e",
        "name": "L-AUTO. S.r.l.",
        "website": "http://www.lauto.mercedes-benz.it",
        "phone": "+39 0775 8859500",
        "country": "Italy",
        "city": "Frosinone",
        "postalCode": "3100",
        "address": "Via Enrico Fermi, 25",
        "description": "description",
        "createdBy": "DataAdmin",
        "updatedBy": "DataAdmin",
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "business": "PTBU",
        "passengerCar": true,
        "van": false,
        "bus": true,
        "unimog": true,
        "truck": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "first": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dealers?direction=ASC&pageSize=10&page=0&size=10&sort=gssnID,asc"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dealers?direction=ASC&pageSize=10&page=0&size=10&sort=gssnID,asc"
    },
    "next": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dealers?direction=ASC&pageSize=10&page=1&size=10&sort=gssnID,asc"
    },
    "last": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dealers?direction=ASC&pageSize=10&page=2&size=10&sort=gssnID,asc"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 10,
    "totalElements": 27,
    "totalPages": 3,
    "number": 0
  }
};

function getDataRecords(providedData: any): Array<any> {
  const dataSet: Array<any> = Object.entries(providedData._embedded)[0];
  dataSet.splice(0, 1); // Delete first property as its name can vary
  return dataSet;
}

console.log(getDataRecords(responseData));
```

Comment: Are you using just Javascript? because `function getDataRecords(providedData: any): Array<any> ` seems to be another language, if it is, please, add the language tag to your question

Comment: @CalvinNunes It is TypeScript actually.

Comment: @HadidAli why you are not using `providedData._embedded. dealerListItemDToes ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have converted your typescript into a Javascript code like

```
let responseData = {
  "_embedded": {
    "dealerListItemDToes": [
      {
        "id": "ab4b23bb-b58d-4012-93ea-702e37ea555a",
        "gssnID": "GSM00000001",
        "companyID": "GCM00000001",
        "mbID": "41010f",
        "name": "GINO RAG. FELICE & FIGLIO - S.p.A.",
        "website": "http://www.gino.mercedes-benz.it",
        "phone": "+39 0171 410777",
        "country": "Italy",
        "city": "Madonna",
        "postalCode": "12100",
        "address": "Madonna dellolmo",
        "description": "description",
        "createdBy": "DataAdmin",
        "updatedBy": "DataAdmin",
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "business": "PVU",
        "passengerCar": true,
        "van": true,
        "bus": false,
        "unimog": true,
        "truck": false
      },
      {
        "id": "b644a324-6858-4ac9-a2ce-a4539cee43a5",
        "gssnID": "GSM00000002",
        "companyID": "GCM00000002",
        "mbID": "42010e",
        "name": "L-AUTO. S.r.l.",
        "website": "http://www.lauto.mercedes-benz.it",
        "phone": "+39 0775 8859500",
        "country": "Italy",
        "city": "Frosinone",
        "postalCode": "3100",
        "address": "Via Enrico Fermi, 25",
        "description": "description",
        "createdBy": "DataAdmin",
        "updatedBy": "DataAdmin",
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "business": "PTBU",
        "passengerCar": true,
        "van": false,
        "bus": true,
        "unimog": true,
        "truck": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "first": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dealers?direction=ASC&pageSize=10&page=0&size=10&sort=gssnID,asc"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dealers?direction=ASC&pageSize=10&page=0&size=10&sort=gssnID,asc"
    },
    "next": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dealers?direction=ASC&pageSize=10&page=1&size=10&sort=gssnID,asc"
    },
    "last": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dealers?direction=ASC&pageSize=10&page=2&size=10&sort=gssnID,asc"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 10,
    "totalElements": 27,
    "totalPages": 3,
    "number": 0
  }
};

function getDataRecords(providedData) {
  const dataSet = Object.entries(providedData._embedded)[0];
  dataSet.splice(0, 1); // Delete first property as its name can vary
  return dataSet;
}

console.log(getDataRecords(responseData));
```

This results in

[image]

and the only problem is that the array that you expect is the first and only element of another array, wrapped around it. So, I solved it like this:

```
let responseData = {
  "_embedded": {
    "dealerListItemDToes": [
      {
        "id": "ab4b23bb-b58d-4012-93ea-702e37ea555a",
        "gssnID": "GSM00000001",
        "companyID": "GCM00000001",
        "mbID": "41010f",
        "name": "GINO RAG. FELICE & FIGLIO - S.p.A.",
        "website": "http://www.gino.mercedes-benz.it",
        "phone": "+39 0171 410777",
        "country": "Italy",
        "city": "Madonna",
        "postalCode": "12100",
        "address": "Madonna dellolmo",
        "description": "description",
        "createdBy": "DataAdmin",
        "updatedBy": "DataAdmin",
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "business": "PVU",
        "passengerCar": true,
        "van": true,
        "bus": false,
        "unimog": true,
        "truck": false
      },
      {
        "id": "b644a324-6858-4ac9-a2ce-a4539cee43a5",
        "gssnID": "GSM00000002",
        "companyID": "GCM00000002",
        "mbID": "42010e",
        "name": "L-AUTO. S.r.l.",
        "website": "http://www.lauto.mercedes-benz.it",
        "phone": "+39 0775 8859500",
        "country": "Italy",
        "city": "Frosinone",
        "postalCode": "3100",
        "address": "Via Enrico Fermi, 25",
        "description": "description",
        "createdBy": "DataAdmin",
        "updatedBy": "DataAdmin",
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "business": "PTBU",
        "passengerCar": true,
        "van": false,
        "bus": true,
        "unimog": true,
        "truck": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "first": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dealers?direction=ASC&pageSize=10&page=0&size=10&sort=gssnID,asc"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dealers?direction=ASC&pageSize=10&page=0&size=10&sort=gssnID,asc"
    },
    "next": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dealers?direction=ASC&pageSize=10&page=1&size=10&sort=gssnID,asc"
    },
    "last": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dealers?direction=ASC&pageSize=10&page=2&size=10&sort=gssnID,asc"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 10,
    "totalElements": 27,
    "totalPages": 3,
    "number": 0
  }
};

function getDataRecords(providedData) {
  const dataSet = Object.entries(providedData._embedded)[0];
  dataSet.splice(0, 1); // Delete first property as its name can vary
  return dataSet[0];
}

console.log(getDataRecords(responseData));
```

Resulting in

[image]

If this solves the problem, then the only modification on your almost correct script is that on the `return` statement I have specified to `return` the 0th element of the outer array, which is the result that you expect.

Comment: I have forgot to mention that property "dealerListItemDToes" can vary and thus should not be hard-coded in the solution.

Comment: @HadidAli can you provide an example where this is a problem?